# Como exibir uma mensagem de quantos registros foram encontrados em um código de busca JS?

Tags: php, javascript

Possuo um código JS que retorna dinamicamente na tela a quantidade de registros encontrados em uma tabela conforme o campo é preenchido. Como faço para retornar uma mensagem exibindo a quantidade de registros encontrados?

- O código que possui o campo que pergunta o nome a ser procurado e a tabela mostrando a listagem dos nomes.

```
    <?php 
        try {
            $selecao = "SELECT * FROM cliente";
            $seleciona_dados = $conexao->prepare($selecao);
            $seleciona_dados->execute();
            $linhas = $seleciona_dados->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        } catch (PDOException $falha) {
            echo "A listagem de dados não foi feita".$falha->getMessage();
            die;
        } catch (Exception $falha) {
            echo "Erro não característico do PDO".$falha->getMessage();
            die;
        }
    ?>

<fieldset>
        <legend> Procurar cliente (Atalho = Alt + w) </legend>
        <p> Procurar cliente pelo nome: 
        <input id="nome" accesskey="w" /> </p>
</fieldset>
    
    <table id="lista" border="1">
        <tr> 
            <th> ID </th>
            <th> Nome </th>
            <th> CPF </th>
            <th> Telefone </th>
            <th> Email </th>
            <th> Cidade </th>
            <th> Bairro </th>
            <th> Rua </th>
            <th> Número </th>
            <th> Ações </th>
        </tr>
        <?php 
            foreach ($linhas as $exibir_colunas){
                echo '<tr>';
                echo '<td>'.$exibir_colunas['cd_cliente'].'</td>';
                echo '<td>'.$exibir_colunas['nome'].'</td>';
                echo '<td>'.substr_replace($exibir_colunas['cpf'], '***.***', 4, -3).'</td>';
                echo '<td>'.$exibir_colunas['telefone'].'</td>';
                echo '<td>'.$exibir_colunas['email'].'</td>';
                echo '<td>'.$exibir_colunas['cidade'].'</td>';
                echo '<td>'.$exibir_colunas['bairro'].'</td>';
                echo '<td>'.$exibir_colunas['rua'].'</td>';
                echo '<td>'.$exibir_colunas['numero'].'</td>';
                echo '<td>'."<a href='/web/form_crud/form_insert_cliente.php/#cad_cli'> Cadastrar </a> ".
                "<a href='/web/form_crud/form_update_cliente.php/#atu_cli'> Atualizar </a> ".
                "<a href='/web/form_crud/form_delete_cliente.php/#exc_cli'> Excluir </a>".'</td>';
                echo '</tr>'; echo '</p>';
            }
        ?>
    </table>  
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/web/js/cliente/select_cliente.js"></script>
```

- Código JS que retorna a filtragem do nome.

```
// JS que retorna a filtragem do nome do cliente
var filtro = document.getElementById('nome');
var tabela = document.getElementById('lista');
filtro.onkeyup = function() {
    var nomeFiltro = filtro.value.toLowerCase();
    for (var i = 1; i < tabela.rows.length; i++) {
        var conteudoCelula = tabela.rows[i].cells[1].innerText;
        var corresponde = conteudoCelula.toLowerCase().indexOf(nomeFiltro) >= 0;
        tabela.rows[i].style.display = corresponde ? '' : 'none';
    }
}
```

Comment: Crie um contador e o incremente a cada iteração onde  `corresponde` seja `true`.

Comment: Acho que não entendi bem como fazer.

Comment: `if (corresponde ) contador++;` após o loop na variável contador estará o soma de registros filtrados.

Comment: Isso dentro do ```for (var i = 1; i < tabela.rows.length; i++){```?

Comment: Lembre-se que antes de usar uma variável tem que a declarar.

Comment: Conseguiu resolver?

Comment: Ainda não consegui

Comment: Dê uma olhada nesse código https://ideone.com/Fj3RCd

Comment: @AugustoVasques acho que deu pra entender, mas tarde eu faço o teste.

Comment: Ainda não deu certo, teria que mostrar uma mensagem de quantos resultados aparecem.

Comment: No console não aparece a quantidade de resultados exibidos. Pegue esse valor `contador` e monte a mensagem da forma que lhe convier.

Comment: É verdade, acabei esquecendo o que fazia o console.